# Is it possible to save data from a network analyzer?

Tags: measurement, network, s-parameters

Im using N9917A Network Analyzer for measuring s-parameter values. I have connected the VNA to PC via Ethernet cable, where I can view the resulting plots of s-parameter values. If i get 15 plots of s-parameters, then I can save the values as csv file manually for each plot. My doubt is, Is there a way to save the values as csv file automatically without having to save it manually. I'm new to using the N9917A. The manual isn't of much help here.Please help.thanks!!

Comment: Take a picture with you smartphone, then use image processing to find each point coordinates.

Comment: Many instruments with ethernet like that have a web interface, have you tried simply pointing your browser to the IP of the instrument? If so, you may be able to ftp and all sorts of other good things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  What you will need to do is control the instrument over VXI-11 or USBTMC and issue the proper commands to perform the measurement, read the data you want, and write it out to files in the format you want.  I would personally recommend using python and python-vxi11 or python-usbtmc, but there are numerous other options including labview and various VISA wrappers.